# Dropzone js upload validation with multiple files

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone.js

I am currently working on with **Dropzonejs** for uploading files. For each file I am attaching a form field. I have to do something like this, if the form field attached with that file is not empty, I want to upload. Else, I show error message below the thumbnail. I have pretty much accomplished this.

The only problem I am facing is, suppose there are 3 files selected. 1st one doesn't have the form field attached but 2nd and 3rd have form field attached. The error message is shown saying the form field is required. But the rest of the files, 2nd and 3rd are not uploaded. It only uploads when I provide the required field on the 1st one.

So, my question is how do I upload only those that have form field attached but leave the rest in the Dropzone area for the user to fill the form field?

**Update:** 
 Once the files are added, the user is required to put the values in the form field. If the form field is not filled, error message is shown and the file is not uploaded but remain in the queue. Else, if the field is filled, the file is uploaded.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

You might hook into an [event](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#events).

There is the `accept` function:

> is a function that gets a file and a done function as parameter. If the done function is invoked without a parameter, the file will be processed. If you pass an error message it will be displayed and the file will not be uploaded. This function will not be called if the file is too big or doesn't match the mime types.

```
dz.options = {
    accept: function(file, done) {
        if (valid) {
            done();
        }
        else {
            done("error message");
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this seems to be called automatically and immediately after a drop.

You might find the other events more appropriate for your app e.g. `send: function(file, xhr, formData)`.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort. Actually, I didn't explain it completely. The form field is added after the file is added. So the user can specify the purpose of the file. So the addedfile event doesn't work. I am doing something on the processing event and change the file.status to Added but the file even without the form field gets uploaded. Is there anyway I can preventDefault for that specific file and let the dropzone upload rest which has the form field?

Comment: In one of my projects I had to track the Dropzone queue with my own collection. I switched off autoProcessQueue and ignored Dropzone's queue. This was for custom resizing so I was basically _just using Dropzone as an UI_ and managed my own file queues. That's probably what you may need to do.

Comment: Maybe just switching off auto process and calling `dz.processQueue()` directly yourself would be sufficient.

Comment: Thank you again! I think I have to do the same as you said. If you don't mind, what are the dropzone methods that are necessary for manual queuing? I have already switched off the autoProcessQueue but when I hit upload button, I initialize the upload by calling processQueue function.

Comment: Before you call processQueue() try using [`getAcceptedFiles()`](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#dropzone-methods) and checking the collection.

Comment: Which methods? I just scanned the event list in the docs for the triggers that seemed to fired at an appropriate time.

Comment: Yes I did use that. Then I looped but don't know how to not include that file. Is there any way to skip that file which doesn't have form input but still put in queue so the user can see the error message, correct it and upload when s/he hits upload button next time?

Comment: There's a `name` and `accepted` attribute. These are not in the docs but I found them with `console.log(file)`. You might try attaching your own `file.foo = "x"`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90500/discussion-between-rossi-robinsion-and-jasen).

Comment: Hey @Jansen, I got better understanding from your suggestions. What I came up with is when the upload but is clicked, I validate the form input and pass to the Dropzone uploadFile(file) function when the files have form input. Otherwise, put them on the queue. Cheers!